# Java, method prints both options from if/else

Tags: java, if-statement, printing

Hi this is some code I've constructed for a project which calls several other methods to print a statement about the person. My problem is its printing in double and appears to be running through both if/else statements.

How can I prevent this? if needed I can add the text from my terminal. Code below;

```
 void printPersonDescription(String name, boolean sex, int age) {

    if(sex == true && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) > 1) {
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " she has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " years left until she is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + "."); 
    }
    else if(sex == false && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) > 1) {
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " he has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " years left until he is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + ".");
    }
    if (sex == true && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) <= 1) {
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " she has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " year left until she is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + "."); 
    }
    else {
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " he has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " year left until he is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + ".");
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't check the whole code. But aren't you missing an else before the third if ??

Comment: You mean to say it printing from first If block and last else block. I think it should. You missed an else in the third block may be.

Comment: Pause to think about how can you make it *maintainable*.

Answer (score 4):

Note how similar your four cases are. You are just changing some words in the line you print. Those four if/else blocks can be simplified to this:

```
void printPersonDescription(String name, boolean sex, int age) {
    int years = yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age);
    String gender = sex ? "she" : "he";
    String plural = years > 1 ? "s" : "";
    println(name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
    " " + gender + " has " + years + " year" + plural + " left until " + gender + " is " + 
    nextMaturityLevel(age) + "."); 
}
```

Also, you can make the `println` a bit more readable by using `String.format` (assuming that the maturity levels are strings)

```
String.format("%s is %s. At %d %s has %d year%s left until %s is %s.", 
        name, getMaturityLevel(age), age, gender, years, plural, gender, 
        nextMaturityLevel(age))
```

Answer (score 2):

Third `if` condition should be `else if` in your code to avoid double printing.

Instead of:

```
if (sex == true && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) <= 1) {
```

Use:

```
else if (sex && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) <= 1) {
```

btw you don't need to use `if (boolVar == true)` you can just use `if (boolVar)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 void printPersonDescription(String name, boolean sex, int age) {

    if(sex == true && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) > 1) {
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " she has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " years left until she is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + "."); 
    }
    else if(sex == false && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) > 1) {
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " he has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " years left until he is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + ".");
    }
    else if (sex == true && yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) <= 1) {    
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " she has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " year left until she is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + "."); 
    }
    else {
        println (name + " is " + getMaturityLevel(age) + ". " + "At " + age + 
        " he has " + yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) + " year left until he is " + 
        nextMaturityLevel(age) + ".");
    }

}
```

You need add `else` before the third `if`. Otherwise, the final `else` statement will match the third `if`, thus, the else statement means

```
if(sex != true || yearsUntilNextMaturityLevel(age) > 1)
```